# Is it possible to edit multiple page layouts?

Tags: page-layout

I can't see how this could be done but I thought I'd ask the question anyway.

I have more than 20 different page layouts for Custom Object and I need to add around 30 field on all page layouts to a specific section.

Is is possible to make change in one page layout and copy that specific section in all the page layouts??

I could see that there is an idea available for the same - [Apply Layout Edit to Multiple Layouts](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dke4AAC)

Just checking if there is any workaround availble for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way out to this is:

1. Make change in one page layout.
2. Get the all page layouts extracted in Force.com IDE.
3. Then copy and paste the section from one page layout XML to all others and save.

It will be a bit quicker than doing it manual again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am not getting an option to copy the section in IDE. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Check the xml and try to find the markup for the prticular section you have modified in first page layout. And then copy the entire section xml markup, and then paste in others.